# Best set of blank cards

Tags: playing-cards, do-it-yourself

Where can I get a good cheap set of blank cards? Amazon sells them, but it is apparently difficult to get a pen to work on them.

In my case I ask because I like bohnanza, but can't tolerate the illustrations. Others may have other uses.

Comment: My first thought was to search for stuff related to [1000 Blank White Cards](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4550/1000-blank-white-cards), but it looks like most people play with index cards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was poking around the other day looking for the same answer. [Plaincards.com](http://plaincards.com/) sells software to design your own cards and blank cards to print your designs on. Seems pretty cool, but it looks like you're limited to standard playing card sizes (i.e. no tiny Arkham cards). Their complete product line appears [here](http://www.plaincards.com/Store/shopdisplaycategories.asp). I'm not sure what size cards Bohnanza uses.

I'm in the midst of designing my own game but I need different sized cards (1.5" by 2.5") so their apparent lack of that size is kind of a deal breaker.

[DeLano Service](http://www.delanoservice.com/default.asp) is another site that could get cards made. Sounds to be a bit more fancy that what you're looking for, perhaps more like a prototype company that an supplier of blank cards, but perhaps they'd sell blank cards if asked.

(Note: I have no affiliation with either site.)

Answer (score 4):

Although not a particularly cheap solution, you could use a service like [Artscow](http://www.artscow.com/photo-gifts/Card/Multi-purpose-Cards-Rectangle-394) to print off this redesign of Bohnanza:

http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/239278/bohnanza-redesign-for-the-uppish-and-the-posh

Answer (score 2):

I use blank name cards. I get them from printers or stationers in boxes of 100 for about $1. They're smaller than regular playing cards, and not as durable, but you can also get them in perforated sheets of ten (10) that will go through your printer. You might find other sizes of perforated cards as well.